# How to observe jqgrid data using knockout.js?

Tags: mvvm, jqgrid, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, jqxgrid

I am using knockout.js to create jqgrid and populate the data using observableArray.
(using Knockout-jqGridBinding plugin)
Array for jqgrid data:

```
var initialData = [{
    id: ko.observable(1),
    name: ko.observable("Well-Travelled Kitten"),
    sales: ko.observable(352),
    price: ko.observable(75.95)
}];

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(result);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**HTML**

```
   <table>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: id"/></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: sales"/></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: price"/></td>
    </tr>    
     </tbody>
   </table>
    <table id="items" data-bind="grid: { data: items }" >
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
        <th data-field="actions" style="width:27px;" data-sortable="false"></th>
        <th data-field="name" width="150px" data-editable="true">Item Name</th> 
        <th data-field="sales" data-editable="true">Sales Count</th> 
        <th data-field="price" data-editable="true">Price</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    </table>
```

Now it populates the data in jqgrid and if I change data outside it reflects in grid as well but when I am changing the data in jqgrid using "cellEdit" it's not reflecting.

Comment: JQwidgets are giving same functionality which I want but it is paid.  

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxknockout/grid.htm?fresh

Comment: Eventually I fixed this issue, I have again push the new data in array using "aftersavecell" event, this way every time observable array is updating.

Comment: you can add an answer to your own question, maybe with more details and code samples.